# Why does the Stand-Alone React Native Debugger show an undefined redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-debugger

I’m using the stand-alone React Native Debugger. It connects, but shows the redux state as undefined. I already tried all versions I found by browsing the internet. This approach is the one that shows better results but has this little problem

[image]

The value called "Your Wallet" is the variable totalWallet, that's getting its value from the redux state.

It is working, but the debugger doesn't show this state

I’m declaring the provider as

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={myStore}>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator
                    screenOptions={{
                        headerShown: false
                    }}
                    initialRouteName={'MainLayout'}
                >
                    <Stack.Screen name="MainLayout" component={Tabs} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

Where myStore is:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import rootReducer from './stores/rootReducer';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const myStore = createStore(rootReducer, /* preloadedState, */ composeEnhancers(thunk));
```

and rootReducer is

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import tabReducer from './tab/tabReducer';
import marketReducer from './market/marketReducer';
import logReducer from './log/logReducer';

export default rootReducer = combineReducers({
    tabReducer,
    marketReducer,
    logReducer
});
```

What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: Normally in the store, we should see an object with 3 keys: tabReducer, marketReducer, logReducer, it will be helpful if you can drop also your reducers.

Comment: Hi Soufiane, what do you mean by dropping my reducers?

Comment: I mean the implementation of the 3 reducers, maybe you have something wrong with the initialization of the state.